# Without JPA @Transaction and save() when is the commit done?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, transactions, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

When a method has a @Transaction annatotion, I know the commit is done at the end of the method. But when I don't use @Transaction, it's not clear to me when the commit is done. In my example I don't use @Transaction, do the real change in another service and don't use someRepository .save(), but it still works:

```
    @Service
    public class ServiceA {

        private final SomeRepository someRepository;
        private final ServiceB serviceB;

        public ServiceA(SomeRepository someRepository, ) {
            this.someRepository = someRepository;
            this.serviceB = serviceB;
        }

        // Called from controller
        public void doStuff() {

            var someEntity = someRepository.findById(1);
            serviceB.makeChange(someEntity);

        }

    }

    @Service
    public class ServiceB {

        public ServiceB() {}

        public void makeChange(SomeEntity someEntity) {

            someEntity.setName("Test"); // this is working and committed to the database

        }

    }
```

So actually I have 2 questions:

1. When I don't add a @Transaction annatotion to a method when is the commit done?
2. I don't even have to call someRepository.save(entity)? I thought that worked only when using the @Transaction annotation?

Context:

- Spring Boot 2.2.6
- "spring-boot-starter-data-jpa" as dependency

Answer (score 1):

first one clarification: the @Transactional annotation does not mean there is a commit at end of the method. It means the method joins the transaction (or start a new one - this depends on the propagation attributes to be precise), so the commit (or rollback) will be performed at the end of the transaction, which can (and often does) involve multiple methods with various DB access.
Normally Spring (or another transaction manager) takes care of this (ie disabling auto-commit).

**@Transactional missing**
There is no transactional context so the commit is performed immediately as the database in modified. There is no rollback option and, if there is an error, the data integrity might be violated,

**@Transactional defined**
During the transactions the JPA entities are in managed-state, at the end of the transaction the state is automatically flushed to the DB (no need to call someRepository.save(entity)